# regex for avoding new line characters in input

Tags: java, regex

Regex to avoid the new line characters like CR/LF in a multiline string was provided to validate the provided user input.

```
^(?!\\s*$).+
```

static code analaysis tool has provided additional comments.
properties additionally need to be included in the sanitization: backslash \t (tab) , (‘ single quote), = (equal sign), and for (% percentage sign) which can be combined to ‘0d’ and ‘0a’ to form a CR / LF.

tried with two options like `^(?!\s\t\'\=%*$).+` and `^(?!\s*$)(?!\t*$)(?!\'*$)(?!=*$)(?!%*$).+`

both did not satified tool scan. inputs?

Comment: validate user provided input. yes to avoid the CR/LF in the provided input. if it matches, will throw an exception.

Comment: Please provide *few sample IO*.

Comment: Try `^(?!\\s*$)[^\r\n]+`

Comment: Still the tool complaining on the same.

Comment: Posted an answer, but it's best you add more information including examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[^\v]` to match everything but vertical whitespace.

- `[^…]` matches any character not present.
- `\v` matches all vertical whitespace characters.